# How to replace reactnative existed ios app with newly created reactnative ipa

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-push-notifications, xcode13.2

actually i have old RN-IOS project 0.59,I tried to upgrade react-native IOS project because of environment issues i had to created new react native project and copied all files and run the application as separate project , and i tested through test flight as separate app in app store but now i have to update the old app which was developed 0.59  app with this newly created react native project app , what are required to update the old app ,i am new to this development.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i edited my problem